# How does the cardinality work in Java BitSet?

Tags: java, java-8, bitset

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

BitSet bs1 = new BitSet();
BitSet bs2 = new BitSet();


bs1.set(0);
bs1.set(1);
bs1.set(2);
bs1.set(4);

bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);


System.out.println("bs1 : " + bs1);
System.out.println("bs2 : " + bs2);



System.out.println(bs1.cardinality());
System.out.println(bs2.cardinality());

}
}
```

In this above code, the cardinality of bitset bs1 is found to be 4 and the bs2 is found to be 1. How does the cardinality come as 1 for bs2?

Comment: Regardless of how often you hit the same nail with the hammer, the number of nails in the wall does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Because.. that's what you programmed. I think I see where you're confused.

This:

```java
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
bs2.set(0);
```

Is 1 line that does something (the first `.set(0)` call), and then 5 lines that do nothing whatsoever. `bs2.set(0)` sets the 0th bit to 1. It doesn't set "the next bit". Hence, `bs2` has a single bit that is set: The 0th bit. Hence, its cardinality, which counts the amount of bits that are set, is 1.

This:

```
bs1.set(0);
bs1.set(1);
bs1.set(2);
bs1.set(4);
```

Simply sets the 0th, 1th, 2nd, and 4th bit. That sets a total of 4 bits, hence, cardinality of 4. The bits are, in order from low to high: 11101000.